# How to check and access a function from another object using JavaScript Proxy?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am practicing JavaScript Proxies and want to access a method from another object but with an empty Proxy object:

```js
const data = {
  hello: {
    log() {
      return 'hello log'
    },
  },
  hi: {
    log() {
      return 'hi log'
    },
  },
}

const blankObject = {} // I can just pass the data object but I want an empty one

const proxy = new Proxy(blankObject, {
  get(target, key) {
    const v = target[key]

    if (typeof v === 'function') {
      // if data.hello.log() or data.hi.log()
      return function() {
         return data[key]['WHAT_TO_DO']// access data.hello.log or data.hi.log() here?
      }
    }

    return v
  }
})

proxy.hello.log() // hello log;
```

Basically I'm trying to check if that method property exist in another object. I just want to tell the proxy to get the value from another object without passing it into the constructor.

Comment: *"I want to trick the proxy"*: huh? You are *writing* the proxy yourself. What is your concern?

Comment: What is your concern in wanting this? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you want to use a different object than the object you are proxying. It makes little sense to proxy an empty object instead.

Secondly, if you are going to access the `hello` property of the proxy object, then realise that this `hello` value -- as found in the `data` object -- is *not* proxied, so it is not in this proxy that you should check whether the property is a function. At this point the `log` property is not accessed yet. It's only about the `hello` access that the proxy is aware.

But you can divert the path to the `data` object when `hello` is accessed, by verifying it is indeed a property of the `data` object. So:

```js
const data = {
  hello: {
    log() {
      return 'hello log';
    },
  },
  hi: {
    log() {
      return 'hi log'
    },
  },
}

const blankObject = {};

const proxy = new Proxy(blankObject, {
  get(target, key) {
    if (key in data) return data[key]; // <---
    return target[key]; // default
  }
});

console.log(proxy.hello.log()); // hello log;
```

Comment: That worked! I'm trying to create a library that has this functionality.. and this is a good start for my proxy learning.

Answer (score 1):

still trying to figure out what in the world you are trying to accomplish here. you're trying to add a method from one object, to another object?

```
const blankObject = { hello: data.hello };
```

though this feels a bit hacky. would probably be best to just pass the whole data object into the constructor, so that the blank object has a reference to it, and can use its methods whenever it needs to.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to check if that method property exist in another object. I understand it can be done like your answer, I appreciate it. I just want to maybe trick the proxy to get the value from another object without passing it into the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matters, using a test, no needs to over-engineer!

```js
let data = {
  hello: {
    log() {
      return 'hello log'
    },
  },
  hi: {
    log() {
      return 'hi log'
    },
  },
}

let blankObject = {} // I can just pass the data object but I want an empty one

// We test if the object has a given property and return accordingly 
console.log(

  (blankObject["hello"]) ? blankObject.hello.log() : data.hello.log()

)
```